# Fill TagTreelist field programmatically (SXA)

Tags: sxa, tree-list

I'm having some troubles with filling a TagTreelist field programmatically.
I simply tried the same as for treelist fields as i know it works:

```
string tagID = Search.GetYearTagItem(year, "/sitecore/content/ORV/Websites/Global/Sanofi COM/Data/Tags", "Feature/Experience Accelerator/Taxonomy/Datasource/Tag").ToString(); // returns me the item ID to insert in the treelist 
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("DebugA:"+tagID, this); // this returns me the right ID.
item.Fields["Tags"].Value = tagID;// string : ids separated by pipes
```

But it seems to work differently with TagTreelist because i got the following error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Does anyone know what type my object is supposed to receive ?

Thank you for your help

**EDIT 1**: i confirm you if i remove this line :

```
item.Fields["Tags"].Value = // string : ids separated by pipes
```

the error disappears. The problem definitely comes from the line i guess.

Comment: Are you sure the type of information is the issue? Your error message suggest a null reference.. can you debug and verify that you don't have that issue?

Comment: Yes, that's what i did and i'm 100% sure the variable i use contains the correct id. However i will keep investigating in case people confirm me it should work.

Comment: Can you try 'item["Main Tags"] = // string' without '.Fields'?

Comment: Best would be to add code snippet into your question which is also around the code you already shared. One line of code is not sufficient to precisely say where could be the null reference.

Comment: @MarekMusielak I tried it. The error disappears but my treelist remains empty.

Comment: @PeterProchazka i've added some more code and explanations. In case it helps...

Comment: Please add also code on how you get and save item

Comment: if `item.Fields["Field Name"].Value` throws exception and `item["Field Name"]` does not throw the exception, it means that the item doesn't have a field called `Field Name`. Check if you're editing the correct item and if the field name is correct for sure

Comment: @MarekMusielak that was my problem. The real field name was SxaTags. Tags was just the display name. I didn't notice it. My mistake.
Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: @Slrg i'm having the same problem, i try to programmatically assign tags to an item, i don't get any errors however the tags tree is always empty. i tried item.Fields["SxaTags"].Value and also tried item.Fields[TagsItemID].Value but still same issue. any idea what i might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
item.Fields["Field Name"].Value = "some string";
```

throws null reference exception and

```
item["Field Name"] = "some string";
```

does not throw the exception, it means that the item doesn't have a field called `Field Name`.

Check if you're editing the correct item and if the field name is correct. Most probably the real field name is different (custom fields) or it should be `__Field Name` (for standard Sitecore built-in fields).

Comment: Hello @Marek Musielak i tried this solution however, the tree still appears empty in the sitecore. Any idea what i might be missing?